# Log Google Security Center - which insecure app did I disable?

Tags: google-account, security

By mistake I just disabled some app that Google deemed "insecure" in Google Security Center (I clicked "disable insecure app" and expected a new screen listing the app I was about to disable but it was disabled immediately, and the name was never showed).

Is there a log somewhere where I can see which app I just disabled?